# WP meta_query args not working in function

Tags: custom-field, filters, meta-query

I have three query args for filtering posts in grid. By Author and Status works fine, but ACF meta_query not work. 
I setup field as select:
http://prntscr.com/pi6m66

I need when is selected "Ne" value hide post from grid, but it still display there.

```
    function my_super_filer_function2($query_args){
    global $post;

    $post_author = $post->post_author;
    $query_args['author'] = $post_author;
     $query_args['post_status'] = array('publish', 'future');

    $query_args ['meta_query']= array(
'meta_key' => 'zobrazitnatridy',
'meta_value' => 'Ne',
'meta_compare' => '!='
);
    return $query_args;
}
add_filter('my_super_filter2', 'my_super_filer_function2');
```

What is wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to it just need to to modify your code little bit. See I've update code for you.

```
function my_super_filer_function2($query_args){
    global $post;
    $post_author = $post->post_author;
    $query_args['author'] = $post_author;
    $query_args['post_status'] = array('publish', 'future');
    $query_args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'zobrazitnatridy',
            'value' => 'Ne',
            'compare' => '!='
        )
    );
    return $query_args;
}
add_filter('my_super_filter2', 'my_super_filer_function2');
```